# Navigation bar storing property of the popped view controller

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, uibutton, uinavigationitem

```
 setNavigationBarWithBack(success: {

        self.createGroup()

        }
 }, name: "CREATE GROUP", rightSideImage: "nextIcon")
```

This is my extension call to create a navbar with a back button and a right button if needed.
If I need a right side button I can give an image name and a button will be created.

the code is,

```
func setNavigationBarWithBack(success: @escaping (()->()), name:String, imageName:String = "backIcon", rightSideImage:String) {

        let leftBtnContainerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
        let leftBtn = UIButton(frame: leftBtnContainerView.frame)
        let leftImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 9, height: 16))
        leftImageView.image = UIImage(named:imageName)
        leftImageView.center = leftBtnContainerView.center
        leftImageView.imageDirection = 1
        leftBtnContainerView.addSubview(leftImageView)
        leftBtnContainerView.addSubview(leftBtn)

        if rightSideImage.count > 0 {
        let rightSideView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
        let rightSideBtn = UIButton(frame: rightSideView.frame)
        let rightSideimageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
        rightSideimageView.image = UIImage(named:rightSideImage)
        rightSideimageView.center = leftBtnContainerView.center
        rightSideimageView.imageDirection = 1
        rightSideView.addSubview(rightSideimageView)
        rightSideView.addSubview(rightSideBtn)

        rightSideBtn.actionHandle(controlEvents: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside,
        ForAction:{() -> Void in
            success()
        })

        let rightSideBarBtnControl = UIBarButtonItem(customView: rightSideView)
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [rightSideBarBtnControl]
        }

        leftBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(returnBack), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
        let back = UIBarButtonItem(customView: leftBtnContainerView)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [back]
        self.navigationItem.title = name
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.white, NSAttributedString.Key.font:UIFont(name:"Poppins-Medium", size: 15)!]
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)

    }
}

extension UIButton {
    private func actionHandleBlock(action:(() -> Void)? = nil) {
        struct __ {
            static var action :(() -> Void)?
        }
        if action != nil {
            __.action = action
        } else {
            __.action?()
        }
    }

    @objc private func triggerActionHandleBlock() {
        self.actionHandleBlock()
    }

    func actionHandle(controlEvents control :UIControl.Event, ForAction action:@escaping () -> Void) {
        self.actionHandleBlock(action: action)
        self.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("triggerActionHandleBlock")), for: control)
    }
}
```

The problem is,
 On using this code when I go back to the previous view controller and that view controller has a right side button and action.
and when I tap it the last view controller right button action (the VC I just returned back from) gets executed even though I am not in that view controller this completion block calls that one.

And one more thing here to notice is Sam using a common view controller for every view controller to write some common code that's applicable.

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?